# Shall I commit solr file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, solr, sunspot-rails

I have added the full text search by sunspot gem and apache solr. I  got many new files in my project. I don't know, is it right, but I commited this files:

```
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/_rest_managed.json 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/admin-extra.html 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/currency.xml 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/elevate.xml 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/lang/stopwords_en.txt 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/protwords.txt 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/schema.xml 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/scripts.conf 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/solrconfig.xml 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/spellings.txt 
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/synonyms.txt 
solr/default/core.properties 
solr/default/data/index/segments_1
solr/default/data/index/write.lock 
solr/development/core.properties 
solr/development/data/index/segments_1
solr/development/data/index/write.lock 
solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid 
solr/solr.xml 
solr/test/core.properties 
solr/test/data/index/segments_1
solr/test/data/index/write.lock
```

After this commit I have got files:

```
new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1.fdt
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1.fdx
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1.fnm
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1.nvd
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1.nvm
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1.si
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1_1.liv
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.doc
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.pos
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.tim
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.tip
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2.fdt
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2.fdx
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2.fnm
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2.nvd
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2.nvm
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2.si
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.doc
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.pos
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.tim
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.tip
    new file:   solr/development/data/index/segments_5
    new file:   solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000000
    new file:   solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000001
    new file:   solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000002
    new file:   solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000003

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
    modified:   app/views/posts/index.html.erb
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2.fdt
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2.fdx
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2.fnm
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2.nvd
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2.nvm
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2.si
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.doc
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.pos
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.tim
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.tip
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/segments_1
    deleted:    solr/development/data/index/segments_5

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    solr/development/data/index/_4.fdt
    solr/development/data/index/_4.fdx
    solr/development/data/index/_4.fnm
    solr/development/data/index/_4.nvd
    solr/development/data/index/_4.nvm
    solr/development/data/index/_4.si
    solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.doc
    solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.pos
    solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.tim
    solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.tip
    solr/development/data/index/segments_9
    solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000004
    solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000005
    solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000006
    solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000007
```

What files I need commit, add .gitignore, add to my projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**git ignore:**

```
*/data/*
*/dataimport.properties
```

For example:

```
 solr/development/data/*
 solr/development/conf/dataimport.properties
```

dataimport.proporties contains last indexed time and other dynamic variables

```
#Thu Nov 17 16:21:03 GMT 2016
last_index_time=2016-11-17 16\:21\:03
development.last_index_time=2016-11-17 16\:21\:03
```

solr/development/data/  - full indexed core with cache filters. 
**Commit:**

**All other files are happy to be committed.**

solr/development/conf/ - main core settings (schema.xml, solrconfig.xml etc)